# Square root link function

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, link-function

I'm running a `glm` that estimates a Gaussian variable of production in kilograms using different independent variables. I found a problem of heteroskedasticity so I tried different transformations of my variable. The convenient one I found is the square root, so I transformed my dependent variable using square root and everything was fine. However, I found a problem interpreting the estimated parameters. So I'm wondering if there is a square root link function in R so that the `glm()` function could do the back transformation of the parameters to the original scale.

Comment: There is a link function called "power". Call that as "power(0.5)" that will return a link function object you can use. For information type ?power at the prompt.

Comment: Something is unclear about your post -- how would a glm with a square root link function\*\*  "backtransform parameters" of a model you fitted to a transformed response? Can you explain what you're attempting here? there may be a better way to do it. $\quad$ \*\*(which R can do; the poisson and quasi families should be able to use it; see `?family`)

Answer (score 0):

The inverse function of a square root of a number is its square. So, if the one has a mean $\pm$ SD in the transformed coordinates, then in the original coordinates that is just

mean$^2$, (mean $+$ SD)$^2-$(mean)$^2$,  (mean $-$ SD)$^2-$(mean)$^2$. However, in that case, the mean$^2$ will not be the mean of the original model. Rather it will be the transformed mean of the secondary model.

In glm one has the option of Poisson regression modelling, which may be what you need to do. In practice, Poisson error is proportional to the square root of the magnitude of the variable.

Comment: I'd suggest removing the "Good grief, " bit. You sound exasperated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "fit the data with the normal squared distribution" means?  It's difficult to see how a $\chi^2(1)$ family in a GLM would handle most forms of heteroscedastic errors, so I figure I must not understand your recommendation.

Comment: @whuber Right, misread question.